# Debug text messages to crash log output

Tags: xcode, swift

How can I add my custom debug messages to crash log output?
I can get crash logs from iOS devices or Mac OS, but it will be much easier to analyze crash logs if I see my debug messages that my application prints (e.g.: "*Launched\nTrying to connect…\nBoom! Crash!*").
So I can see much more information about things happened before crash.

Or it can be possible only with custom crash logging libraries?

Comment: Do you mean if the app is not connected to Xcode? If it is, println() should work fine.

Comment: Will print() be displayed in crash logs sent from Apple when app is crashed at user's iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `NSLog()` it writes data to Apple System Log, `print` doesn't do that.

Also you may check some frameworks like [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack), that do what you want.